# What is the difference between stackless and stackfull coroutines?

Tags: asynchronous, coroutine

I am trying to wrap my head around coroutines. As far as I understand, coroutines are just functions except they can be suspended at any point of their execution. So doesn't that mean a coroutine will always need a stack to keep track of all the variables that it had access to before suspension? Am I misunderstanding something basic? Where am I wrong in my assumption?